# Difference of a variable name with '!' in Velocity Template

Tags: templates, variables, initialization, declaration

What is the difference between the following two declarations and how does is work?

`name="$!{fieldName}"` and `name="$fieldName"`

Comment: code formatting; fixed spelling and title

Answer (score 3):

**Quiet Reference Notation:**

When Velocity encounters an undefined reference, its normal behavior is to output the image of the reference. For example, suppose the following reference appears as part of a VTL template.

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="$email"/>
```

When the form initially loads, the variable reference $email has no value, but you prefer a blank text field to one with a value of "$email". Using the quiet reference notation circumvents Velocity's normal behavior; instead of using $email in the VTL you would use $!email. So the above example would look like the following:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="$!email"/>
```

Now when the form is initially loaded and $email still has no value, **an empty string** will be output **instead of "$email"**.

Source: https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html